# How to loop this array?

Tags: reactjs, loops, nested-loops

I'm trying to display the values of this array using map method. The data should be displayed in JSX like "local - event - age ". What is the best practice in terms of performance? I would like to avoid nested map.

```
const data = [
  {
    cambridge: {
      event: "birthday",
      age: "free"
    },
    boston: {
      event: "beer tasting",
      age: "only adults"
    },
    watertown: {
      event: "porch music festival",
      age: "free"
    }
  }
];
```

I tried something like that but it's not the format "local - event - age". Thank you!

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(obj => (
        <div>
          <div>{Object.keys(obj).map(key => console.log(key))}</div>
          <div>{Object.values(obj).map(key => console.log(key.event, key.age))}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to update your data structure to be an array of "locals"? That would remove the need for `Object.keys()` and make the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro That would be perfect but the backend is sending me the data like that.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to avoid the nested map, would be changing the structure in the backend, so you don't need to iterate twice. If that's not an option, you can use one of the answers below. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `index` from the first map to find the right array item and use the `keys` to access the values. Something like this:

```
const childrenElements = data.map((obj, idx) => 
    Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      return (
        <p>
          {key} - {data[idx][key].event} - {data[idx][key].age}
        </p>
      );
    })    
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{childrenElements}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hugle-1eip0

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
        {
            data.map(obj => {
                Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div>{key}</div>
                            <div>{obj[key].event} - {obj[key].age}</div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            })
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You are missing some small things there @Matt. First, you need to wrap your `<div>`s in a single HTML Element. Then you need to include some returns. The format asked by the OP is also a little bit different, since you have 2 lines. If you just copy that code into codesandbox or some tool like that, you will see the errors. The logic to get the data is correct, but the code itself needs some updates to be used :)

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro good points, I've fixed up the answer. I didn't include the `console.log()` format as it seemed like it was for debugging in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use es6 Template Strings to format like "local - event - age "

Your code look like this,

```
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(obj => (
        <div>
          <div>{Object.values(obj).map(key => console.log(`local - ${key.event} - ${key.age}`))}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: His issue is not about the string formatting, but about the data structure. So, simply using String Templates, doesn't solve the problem. Also, this answer is missing the "local". You are only printing "event" and "age" :)